# Repeats of all binary strings of length k

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question seems like it should be known, but I was not able to find it anywhere.

How many binary strings of length $n$ are required so that for every $k$ positions in these strings, all $2^k$ possible subsequences occur?

For example, suppose $n=3$, and $k=2$. We want a set of binary strings of length $3$ so that if you look at the first and third symbols (or first two, or last two), you will see all $4$ patterns $00$, $01$, $10$, and $11$. For example, the strings with an even number of $1$s $\{ 000, 011, 110, 101\}$ induce all subsequences on each set of two positions.

Let $f(n,k)$ be the minimum number. Trivially, $f(n,k) \ge 2^k$ so $f(3,2)=4$.

I am interested in precise upper and lower bounds for $f(n,k)$. Bounds that are within a constant of each other (independent of $n$ and $k$) suffice for my purposes.

Comment: The quantifiers are not clear to me.

Comment: consider m strings of length n of zeros and ones. Say we arrange them in m rows. Resulting in an $m\times n$ matrix. The question is what is the minimum m so that for every k columns all possible 2^k binary combinations appear in the rows. I am interested in results of the form $f(n,k)\le m \le c f(n,k)$ with c a fixed numerical constant independent of n and k. For example obviously m must be bigger than $2^k$

Comment: You are supposed to be able to pick *any* k columns; not just adjacent columns?

Comment: I also don't exactly understand what you want, but probably this might help. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence)

Comment: Anthony Quas: yes any k columns

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify it? It should be understandable for readers who do not look at the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orthogonal arrays were mentioned in another answer, but you are not requiring that each $k$-tuple occurs exactly once in every set of $k$ columns, but rather that each $k$-tuple occurs *at least once* in every set of $k$ columns.

What you are looking for is called a [covering array](http://math.nist.gov/coveringarrays/coveringarray.html). In the usual notation for covering and orthogonal arrays, $v$ is the size of the alphabet ($2$ in this case), $k$ corresponds to your $n$, and $t$ corresponds to your $k$. Some known upper bounds for the number of rows for small values of $t,k,v$ are listed in http://www.public.asu.edu/~ccolbou/src/tabby/catable.html - you are interested in the numbers for $(t,k,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition:** A $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ orthogonal array ($t \leq k$) (also called an orthogonal array of power/strength $t$) is a $λv^t × k$ array whose entries are chosen from a set $X$ with $v$ points such that in every subset of $t$ columns of the array, every $t-$tuple of points of $X$ appears in exactly $λ$ rows. I have used the standard notation for letters.

It seems to me the OP is looking for orthogonal arrays with minimal number of rows over the set $X=\{0,1\}$ with $k=n,\lambda=1,$ and $t=k$ because he wants every $k-$tuple to occur in every possible $k$ positions.

There are literally hundreds of papers and tens of constructions in this area. There are some lower bounds known for existence. I suggest he start with reading the Wikipedia entry and then moving on to tutorial papers of which there are plenty. Happy googling!

Comment: Also, orthogonal arrays for $\lambda=1$, $v=2$ exist only when $k=t$, $k=t+1$ or $t=1$.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. You're right in OA notation his $n$ (length of sequence) is their $k.$ I wasn't aware of the existence restraint you stated.

Comment: Thanks these are great refs. It seems though orthogonal array means every combination appears exactly once. Is there some thing more specific if we want at least once?

Comment: @Anahita, you can choose $\lambda\geq 1$ and have everything appear at exactly $\lambda$ times. The other answer is more directly relevant to what you asked. On the other hand, I am unsure if any infinite families of covering arrays are known.